# Создание пакета с модулем, ошибка

Tags: python, django

Ребят. Создал пакет с модулем. Но что-то не работает его вызов:
В самом скрипте вызываю модуль таким образом:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/alex/redmouse/dz/homework3')
from pack import *
```

В пакете в **init**.py следующий код:

```
from moduleif import *
```

В итоге выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "work56.py", line 3, in <module>
from pack import *
File "/home/alex/redmouse/dz/homework3/pack/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from moduleif import *
ImportError: No module named 'moduleif'
```

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Файл в moduleif.py в папке с пакетом присутствует.

Comment: попробуйте `from .moduleif import *`

Comment: Или `from . import *`. Но по-моему `__init__.py` лучше оставить вообще пустым

Comment: Спасибо. Вариант `from .moduleif import *` - подошёл идеально!

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы импортировать что-то из модуля в этой же папке используйте следующий код

```
 from .moduleif import *
```